# how to enhance images captured from an old film recorder

Tags: images, image-quality, image-editing

I have 4 frames from an historical source showing an animation of a statistical algorithm (multidimensional scaling), ca. 1962.  They were captured by a film recorder connected to a CRT display.  A movie version can be found at http://stat-graphics.org/movies/multidimensional-scaling.html

I want to publish these in a book on the history of data visualization, and wonder if there is some way I can enhance them digitally to make the patterns of points on the black background more visible. What is important to see is how the configuration of points changes from frame to frame.

Are there any tools I could use to make this better?

Here is the figure, composed from the 4 separate frames.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use just about any half decent raster image editor, such as Photohsop, PaintShopPro, Affinity Photo, or even free Open Source software such as GIMP.

A Levels adjustment would fix it.  This example was made in GIMP

[image]

Comment: Thx Billy.  I'm not familiar with the Levels adjustment in these tools. I'll accept your answer if you or someone else can point me to the parameters to change.

Comment: @user101089 In GIMP it's in the main menu under: *Colours > Levels*. Then move the tiny triangle-shaped arrow sliders under the Input Levels histogram into the position as shown in the screenshot above, or tweak them until you are happy with the result.